# Django: How do I check for duplicates before bulk_create (when defining the object)?

Tags: python, django

I would like to define an object and check if it is a
duplicate before creating it,as shown below.

`if data['title'] in videos:`
I'm hoping I can determine it this way.
How can I determine duplicates?

```py
videos = []
throughs = []
for datas in files:
    for data in datas:
        tags = data["tags"].split()
        tag_pks = list(
            set([Tag.objects.get_or_create(name=tag)[0].pk for tag in tags])
        )

        #Around here, we want to make sure that the list called videos already contains data['title'].
        video = Video(
            title=data["title"],
            thumbnail_url=data["thumbnail_url"],
            preview_url=data["preview_url"],
            embed_url=data["embed_url"],
            embed_source=data["embed_source"],
            duration=data["duration"],
            published_at=data["published_at"],
        )
        for tag_pk in tag_pks:
            throughs.append(
                Video.tags.through(video_id=video.pk, tag_id=tag_pk)
            )
        videos.append(video)
Video.objects.bulk_create(videos)
Video.tags.through.objects.bulk_create(throughs)
```

Comment: There must be unique field in the Video Class, like if the 'title' is unique you can add `if` statement before `videos.append(video)`. The if will be like `if data['title'] not in videos:videos.append(video)`

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to write an important thing. The combination of `title` and `thumbnail_url` must be unique. Also, `if data['title'] not in videos` will result in `not in` even if it already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you said if the title and the thumbnail_url are unique, do it like this:

```
videos = []
throughs = []
for datas in files:
    for data in datas:
        tags = data["tags"].split()
        tag_pks = list(
            set([Tag.objects.get_or_create(name=tag)[0].pk for tag in tags])
        )

        #Around here, we want to make sure that the list called videos already contains data['title'].
        video = Video(
            title=data["title"],
            thumbnail_url=data["thumbnail_url"],
            preview_url=data["preview_url"],
            embed_url=data["embed_url"],
            embed_source=data["embed_source"],
            duration=data["duration"],
            published_at=data["published_at"],
        )
        for tag_pk in tag_pks:
            throughs.append(
                Video.tags.through(video_id=video.pk, tag_id=tag_pk)
            )

        # before you put it in the list check if this obj is in the list already
        # since it is empty for the first loop we will jump to the else and add the first one
        if videos:

            # then loop that list
            for vid in videos:

                # and check if the new obj is in that list
                if vid.title != video.title and vid.thumbnail_url != video.thumbnail_url:

                    # if the condition is true that means it is not in the list so we can add
                    # otherwise we will skip
                    videos.append(video)
        else:
            videos.append(video)

Video.objects.bulk_create(videos)
Video.tags.through.objects.bulk_create(throughs)
```

Comment: Thank you. But doesn't this mean that you have to `append` every time you don't want to duplicate?

Comment: don't you want to avoid the duplicates?

Comment: No problem. Solved. Thanks!